# Android :Share image with text pre-filled on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, screensharing

I guys, so... i can't share image in facebook with some text pre-filled, using facebook sdk. 
I use this code in my application :

```
SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(bitmap)
            .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
            .build();

ShareDialog.show(this, content);
```

and i read on facebook docs that ther is a method of SharePhoto.Builder object to set a string as a caption :

```
SharePhoto.Builder().setCaption(String capition)
```

but when i add it on my sharePhoto object, it seems it doesn't exist.
So how can i add a pre-filled text on my post ?
The photo/image is a screeshot of my application !
Anybody have a solution ?

Comment: You know that the Facebook Platform Policy say that the user have to type the caption them self?

Comment: In my application/game the user get a score, i take a screenshot, and if the user click on fb icon i want to share his score with a prefilled text.
Does facebook provide any methods to do that ?

Comment: Prefilling the message is not allowed so it doesn't matter if it is possible

Comment: @WizKid Is it also in the docs documented instead of in the Facebook Platform Policy?

Comment: I don't think it is in the docs. Why?

Comment: I needed to know it for sure. Found it, see my answer.

Comment: @Bob91 i have same problem if you have solution than guid me thanks

Comment: I tried many solutions, but nothing ! I think that is a facebook policy.

Answer (score 1):

pre-fill text-with-image is no longer work read new privacy and policy

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Answer (score 0):

> Populate the user message parameter with content a user manually entered earlier in your app's flow

Explained with a video:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill